# Python Django Invalid Input Syntax Error for Int even though it isn't supposed to be an integer

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am making an e-commerce app using Python, Django 2.1, and PostgreSQL. When I click on one of the categories to show products specific to that category, it tells me that I have a data error. Apparently, in the URL, there is a string when there is supposed to be an integer. I don't understand this. Please help

I have tried many different things, but none seem to work.

My URL Patterns:

```
    path('products/phones/', product_views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(template_name='products/category_details/phones.html'), name='phones'),
    path('products/laptops/', product_views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(template_name='products/category_details/laptops.html'), name='laptops'),
    path('products/desktops/', product_views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(template_name='products/category_details/desktops.html'), name='desktops'),
    path('products/keyboards/', product_views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(template_name='products/category_details/keyboards.html'), name='keyboards'),
    path('products/mice-and-mouse-pads/', product_views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(template_name='products/category_details/mice.html'), name='mice'),
    path('products/headsets/', product_views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(template_name='products/category_details/headsets.html'), name='headsets'),
    path('products/printers-scanners-and-fax/', product_views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(template_name='products/category_details/printers.html'), name='printers'),
    path('products/consoles/', product_views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(template_name='products/category_details/consoles.html'), name='consoles'),
    path('products/misc/', product_views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(template_name='products/category_details/misc.html'), name='misc'),
```

The error received is:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "Phones"
LINE 1: ...s_product" WHERE "products_product"."category_id" = 'Phones'
```

My Views

```
    model = Category
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    template_name = 'products/category_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'categories'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Query Sets
        context['phones'] = Product.objects.filter(category='Phones')

        context['laptops'] = Product.objects.filter(category='Laptops')
        context['total_laptops'] = len(Product.objects.filter(category='Laptops'))

        context['desktops'] = Product.objects.filter(category='Desktops')
        context['total_desktops'] = len(Product.objects.filter(category='Desktops'))

        context['keyboards'] = Product.objects.filter(category='Keyboards')
        context['total_keyboards'] = len(Product.objects.filter(category='Keyboards'))

        context['mice'] = Product.objects.filter(category='Mice and Mouse Pads')
        context['total_mice'] = len(Product.objects.filter(category='Mice and Mouse Pads'))

        context['printers'] = Product.objects.filter(category='Printers, Scanners, and Fax Machines')
        context['total_printers'] = len(Product.objects.filter(category='Printers, Scanners, and Fax Machines'))

        context['consoles'] = Product.objects.filter(category='Consoles')
        context['total_consoles'] = len(Product.objects.filter(category='Consoles'))

        context['miscellaneous'] = Product.objects.filter(category='Miscellaneous')
        context['total_miscellaneous'] = len(Product.objects.filter(category='Miscelaneous'))

        return context
```

Comment: You need to show the code for CategoryDetailView, as well as the full error traceback.

Comment: It looks like the error inside your view, you're trying to filter query by `category_id` witch is `int` by sending `str` filter `Phones`